# how to add the underscore module with angular 2?

Tags: angular

I installed the underscore module and tsd module but it won't work
i tried the command npm install tsd

[screenshot of the error in underscore module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKgqA.png)

Comment: Did you import the <script> tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is related with typings, no underscore itself.

Some packages (as underscore) does not come up with a definition file, this file is important to typescript for autocomplete features, etc.

The solution is install the type file, you can found the installation instructions [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/underscore)

NPM manage all the types files. You can find [here](http://microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch/) a type search.